# Google maps v3 - draw polylines with marker

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a script from Google API source example and I need create function for delete marker with line. There is no problem with the removal of the last point, but with the removal of the middle points.

```
var map;
    var poly;
    marker=new Array();

    function initializeAddRoute() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6
      };
       setMapCenter();
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-addRoute'),
          mapOptions);


    var polyOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3
      };

        poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
        poly.binder = new MVCArrayBinder(poly.getPath());
        poly.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);
    }


    function addLatLng(event) {
       var path = poly.getPath();
        path.push(event.latLng);
        var len = path.getLength();
        var markers = marker.length;

        marker[len] = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          title: '#' + len,
          map: map,
          draggable : true,
          id: len
        });
        marker[len].bindTo('position', poly.binder, (len-1).toString());
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[len], 'click', deletePosition);
    }

    function deletePosition(event){
        ????????    
    }
```

This is a script for delete last point.

```
function deletePosition(event){
alert(this.id);
    var path = poly.getPath();
path.removeAt(this.id-1);

marker.splice( $.inArray(this.id,marker),1);
this.setMap(null);              
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through your array of markers.

```
for (var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++) {
    // Delete marker
    marker[i].setMap(null);
    marker.splice(i, 1);
    // Delete polyline point
    poly.getPath().removeAt(i);
}
```

If you want to remove a specific marker, the idea is roughly the same. Please check from this very clear example on how to add, move and remove markers along with polylines:

http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/4bJBx/

Comment: is there something wrong about idea of calling poly.setMap(null); which would also remove it? instead of these path "hacks"

Comment: You mean other than it won't work?  poly.setMap(null) will hide the whole polyline.   A polyline is an array of points, if you want to remove an element from the middle of an array, you need to find it, and delete it; doing that isn't a "hack".

Comment: The function does not work when deleting from the middle of a polyline and can not later move individual points.

Comment: Ok this wasn't very clear from your question. Check the link in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it little bit elegant (for cases when you have another markers on map, that you want not to correspond with polyline markers)
when setting a marker - title it with number of paths of polyline:

```
var polyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            title: ''+path.getLength(),
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map
        });
```

So when you need to remove concrete marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polyMarker, 'rightclick', function() {
            removePoint(polyMarker);
        });
```

And the function is:

```
function removePoint(polyMarker) {
            // Delete marker
            polyMarker.setMap(null);
            // Delete polyline point
            polyLine.getPath().removeAt(polyMarker.getTitle()-1);
}
```